# Hide list view until button is pressed

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, mvvm

Im having text box and list view and when you are pressing on the button 
you are the list view is filled with data ,currently the list view is under the button and the text box and 
always is there and filled after you press on the button.
There is a way to **hide the list view from the page until you press on the button** and requesting the data?

```
public class ModelView
{
    public ModelView()
    {
        GetServiceCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    }

    bool isDataLoaded = false;

    MyCommand goCommand;
    public ICommand GoCommand
    {
        get { return goCommand ?? (goCommand = new MyCommand(() => OnGoCommand(), () => !isDataLoaded)); }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> GetServiceCollection { get; set; }

    void OnGoCommand()
    {
        GetServiceCollection.Clear();

        foreach (var item in _configServiceModel.CollectList)
        {
            GetServiceCollection.Add(item);
        }

        isDataLoaded = true;
        goCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();

    }

......
```

The xaml

```
<Button Content="Go" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Height="21.96" Command="{Binding GoCommand}"/>

<ListView Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="230" 
 Margin="5,20,0,0" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="330" 
 ItemsSource="{Binding GetCollection}" }" >
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ViewModel

```
public class ConfigModelView:INotifyPropertyChanged
{ 
    public ConfigModelView()
    {
        GetServiceCollection=new ObservableCollection<string>();
    }

    bool isDataLoaded;
    public bool IsDataLoaded
    {
        get { return isDataLoaded; }
        set { isDataLoaded = value; OnPropertyChanged("IsDataLoaded"); }
    }
    MyCommand goCommand;
    public ICommand GoCommand
    {
        get{return goCommand ?? (goCommand=new MyCommand(()=>Command(),()=>!isDataLoaded));}
    }
    public ObservableCollection<string> GetServiceCollection{get;set;}

    void Command()
    {
        foreach (var item in _configServiceModel.CollectList)
        {
            GetServiceCollection.Add(item);
        }

        isDataLoaded = true;
        OnPropertyChanged("IsDataLoaded");
        goCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

> BooleanToVisibilityConverter

```
public class BoolToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is bool)
        {
            if ((bool)value)
                return Visibility.Visible;
            else
                return Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

> xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="800">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <Button Content="Go" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Height="21.96" Command="{Binding GoCommand}"/>

    <ListView Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="230" 
 Margin="5,20,0,0" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="330" 
 Visibility="{Binding IsDataLoaded,
Converter= {StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"
ItemsSource="{Binding GetCollection}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: FYI - `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` is provided in WPF by default. Simply declare like this: `<BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>`.

Comment: Thanks for your help!Voted Up I use your code and its working ,but now the when I click on the button I get the data but the button is  enabled what should i change in this case?Btw there is a way to write the code differently other than {return goCommand ?? (goCommand=new MyCommand(()=>Command(),true));   ,maybe in simple way? Thanks in advance

Comment: @RohitVats- when i change to this type I got error in RT do i Need to add something in addition to this

Comment: It wont be true in the second parameter of MyCommand It would be  like get{return goCommand ?? (goCommand=new MyCommand(()=>Command(),()=>!isDataLoaded));}

Answer (score 1):

The best bet here would be to create another property on the ViewModel that you bind the Visibility of the ListView to.  In the *GoCommand* implementation, set this property to visible.

As a side note, your ViewModel doesn't implement **INotifyPropertyChanged**, so you'll need to do that as well to have the visiblity update when the property is changed:

```
private Visibility listViewVisibility;
public Visibility ListViewVisibility
{
    get { return listViewVisibility; }
    set
    {
        if (this.listViewVisibility == value)
            return;

        this.listViewVisibility = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged("ListViewVisibility");
    }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    if(this.PropertyChanged != null)
        this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

The xaml:

```
<ListView Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="230" 
          Margin="5,20,0,0" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="330" 
          Visibility="{Binding ListViewVisibility}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding GetCollection}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Well load your form then in the put "listView1.hide()".

Then create your button event.

Type "listView1.show()".

P.S. you can also set all of those values in your c# code.